# Import models in subdirectories Yii

Tags: php, yii

I'm using the php framework Yii.

When i use: `yii::import('application.models.*');`, all models in models folder will be imported, but i have some models in the sub-directories:

- "/models/subdir1/model1.php"
- "/models/subdir1/subsubdir2/model2.php"
- "/models/subdir1/subsubdir2/model3.php"
- "/models/subdir1/subsubdir2/subsubsubdir3/model4.php"

there are many levels (3, 4 or perhaps 5), and i would like to import all of these models using: `yii::import('application.models.subdir1.*');`

is there any solution to do that ??

and thanks in advance.

Comment: The best way is to use namespaces.

Comment: namespaces require php 5.3.0 or above, and i'm using 5.2.5.

Comment: You don't mention this in your post. Why not to use 5.3? :)

Comment: for the moment i can't use php 5.3, i have to see with the administrator. i'm going to use the solution of schmunk if there is no other solution.

Comment: You can also use PEAR-style class naming (as Zend do).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I can't find it in the guide, it should be available with

```
yii::import('application.models.subdir1.**');
```

http://code.google.com/p/yii/issues/detail?id=1568

[edit] Sorry, didn't read the full page, looks like it was reverted, but you could still get a specific revision to get the code, but it's not recommended by qiang.

Comment: thanks a lot schmunk, it works well, but how could i get this revision, may be i apply these changes: http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/detail?r=2452 ??

Comment: If you really want to use this - because it's reverted, you can get the revision by svn up -r2452 /path/to/YiiBase.php

Another option would be the svn export -r2452 http://code.google.com/..../YiiBase.php and require that file in the first line of your index.php, then it should be the preferred file.

Note: Be careful mixing revisions, I would not suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

I can not find in Yii2 this till now and 
if you want you can do the follow

Extend the content of the class Yii it is located in (/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php) and add in class Yii functions
public static load($path) and 
static function listFolderFiles($dir).
:

Use these examples in your code!

Yii::load('models.*');
- this load all files  in directory models and all files in subdirectories

Yii::load(['models.* ','components.* ']); 
- this load all files in models and components also files in subdirectories

Yii::load(['models.*','components.yourClassFileName']); 
- this load all files in models (and files in subdirectories) and one file in components

public static function load($path = null) with content:

```
    if($path != null){
        $root = self::getAlias('@webroot');
        if(is_array($path)){
            foreach($path as $p){
                $p = str_replace('/', '\\', $root).'/'.str_replace('.','/',$p);
                if(substr($p, -2) == '/*'){
                    $dir = substr($p, 0, -2);
                    self::listFolderFiles($dir);
                } else {
                    require substr($p, 0, -1).'.php';
                }
            }
        }

        if(is_string($path)){

            $path = str_replace('/', '\\', $root).'/'.str_replace('.','/',$path);

            if(substr($p, -2) == '/*'){
                $dir = substr($p, 0, -2);
                self::listFolderFiles($dir);
            } else {
                require $path.'.php';
            }
        }
    }
```

static function listFolderFiles($dir) with content:

```
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) {
                self::listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            } else {
                require $dir.'/'.$ff;
            }
        }
    }
```